# Annual Reviews Condensed Matter Physics Math Font

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to know what math font is used by the journal "Annual Review of Condensed Matter Physics" and how to use it.

Downloading their [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/annual-reviews-style-4-template-condensed-matter-physics/mrvgfqfszktw) and typing some equations appears to simply use the standard math font, not the one that appears in the published articles.

Here are some examples of what the font looks like (taken from different articles):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don’t know about this journal specifically, but a common practice is to have authors submit with one template, and then internally use another with their commercial fonts. In that case, your draft won’t look like the final article.

Answer (score 3):

Running `pdffonts` on an article downloaded from the site yields:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JPCCBF+JansonTextLTStd-Roman         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     96  0
JPCEIG+JansonTextLTStd-Italic        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     97  0
JPCEMG+JansonTextLTStd-Bold          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      98  0
Times-Roman                          Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no       2  0
JPCHKE+CMSY10                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     134  0
JPCIGC+MTSY                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    199  0
JPCIMB+MTEX                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     200  0
JPCICC+RMTMI                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    201  0
JPCIEC+LucidaSansUnicode22           Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     202  0
JPCKIH+MTMI                          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     239  0
JPCJPK+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    240  0
JPCLED+Times-Italic                  Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     262  0
JPCPJO+MinionPro-SemiboldIt          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    287  0
JPCPLO+MyriadPro-Semibold            Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     288  0
JPCPGN+MyriadPro-It                  Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     289  0
JPCPIN+MinionPro-BoldIt              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    290  0
JPCPDM+MinionPro-It                  Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    291  0
JPCPDN+Symbol                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    292  0
JPCOPM+MyriadPro-Regular             Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    293  0
JPCPAN+MyriadPro-Bold                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    294  0
JPDDDJ+MinionPro-Regular             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     344  0
JPDEOA+JansonTextLTStd-BoldItalic    Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     345  0
JPDDCJ+MyriadPro-BoldIt              Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     346  0
JPDJCF+AppleSymbols                  Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    384  0
NNAOEO+JansonTextLTStd-Roman         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    581  0
NNBBIK+JansonTextLTStd-Bold          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     582  0
NNBBKK+JansonTextLTStd-Italic        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     583  0
NNBBPJ+LCIRCLEW10                    Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     584  0
```

From which it seems likely that the font used is [Janson Text](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/janson-text/). The lower case `h` in italics certainly seems to match.

The font is commercial and provided in OpenType format. If you use XeLaTeX or LuaTeX you can use [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec?lang=en) to load it. Search around on this site for more precise instructions.

To use OTF fonts with pdflatex is a bit more complicated, it seems. (I've never tried myself.) There are [some guides out there](https://nek0.eu/posts/2017-07-21-How-to-use-OTF-fonts-with-pdflatex.html) but I cannot vouch for it.